# phonegap run android throw exception

Tags: cordova

"phonegap run android" I got exception after execute using ubuntu.Can anyone tell me where i did wrong.I searched on google but not got solution.

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
/home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:11)
{ [Error: /home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1]
  stack: 'Error: /home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1\n    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)\n    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)\n    at maybeClose (child_process.js:991:16)\n    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1058:5)',
  code: 1 }
   [error] /home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: ur system windows or mac

Comment: ubuntu 13.04 also my system path /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: did u check this   http://julianhigman.com/blog/2013/10/17/notes-on-setting-up-phonegap-on-ubuntu-for-android-app-development/

Comment: NO i will try and let u know

Comment: Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk ant

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install ant try this also

Comment: if everything goes fine than let me know please. i will answer your question in good manner so that other could get benefited

Comment: Throw excetption Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets

Comment: /home/user166/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126 throw e

Comment: http://yaizabailen.com/setting-up-an-android-app-build-environment-with-android-sdk-and-phonegap-in-ubuntu-13-04/ ... check it here

Comment: Hello Sir solved. i am not setting path correctly.Thanks for help me

Comment: Better you answer ur own question briefly and it will help others too

Comment: now I am using phonegap2.9.0.But in cordova 3.4 i m not finding jar file also i m confuse how to integrate with eclipse.can u tell me?

Comment: @ use 2.9.0 bro in 3.4.0 have some issues..later u update

Comment: Okay Do u have any idea about get all acounts? [link](https://github.com/seltzlab/AccountList-Phonegap-Android-Plugin/commit/6eab9640008d9b46a88c2276e0e29f7762690fba) i reffer this link but not working